# Using to/cc/bcc in Outlook contact group

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts

I regularly send out emails to the same group of people, but some are sent the actual email and others only a cc.

Is there a way I can assign certain members in a contact group to the `to` or `cc` fields? Or is this something I can only accomplish using a mail template with pre-defined contacts?

Comment: distribution lists do not have this quality (some To, some cc).  A tmeplate is a good idea. Or you could have two lists (projectA_to, ProjectA_cc)